# AngularJS está limpando os parâmetros de Url

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tenho um sistema com Angular e Java.

Na rota inicial eu leio os parâmetros de url(algumas informações do usuário, como código, etc..) e salvo no $rootScope para acessar por toda a aplicação.

Se eu acessar direto pelo browser, funciona de acordo, o exemplo do link acessado é esse:

http://localhost:3000/#!/login?parametro1=10&parametro2=20

Porém eu tenho um outro sistema que gera esses links e envia por e-mail a alguns destinatários, e eles acessam a partir do e-mail, com esses parâmetros embutidos na url.

Nesses casos, o Angular carrega o link principal, porém ele acaba limpando todos os parâmetros, deixando a url assim apenas:

http://localhost:3000/#!/login

Para fazer a leitura dos parâmetros, estou usando $location.search() com o Angular.

Edit:

> Recupero os parâmetros no "module.run()" do Angular da aplicação.

```
    function run($rootScope, $location) {

     var data = $location.search();

     if (data) {
         $rootScope.parametro1= data.parametro1;
         $rootScope.parametro2= data.parametro2;
     } 

   }
```

> Rotas do angular

```
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    //Route Default
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

    //Routes
    $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
            controller: 'AuthenticationCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })

}
```

> Controller de Login

```
function AuthenticationCtrl($state, $rootScope, $location) {

   var vm = this;
   vm.init = init;

   init();

   function init() {

        //Faço o parse, pois esse parâmetro é sempre inteiro..
        vm.parametro1 = parseInt($rootScope.parametro1);
    }

}
```

> Alguém sabe o por quê desse comportamento?
>
> Como corrigir isso?

Comment: Poderia mostrar o trecho de código onde você prepara as rotas, Geferson?

Comment: Claro @OnoSendai, já atualizo o post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O tratamento padrão de rotas não preserva [querystrings](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/202), e sua rota não está esperando parâmetros. Para todos os fins, a rota

```
#!/login?parametro1=10&parametro2=20
```

É inexistente, então o URL Router encaminha o usuário para o parâmetro definido em `.otherwise()`.

Se você deseja receber parâmetros na sua rota, configure-a da seguinte maneira:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login/:parametro1/:parametro2',
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
        controller: 'AuthenticationCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
```

E emita suas URLs no seguinte formato:

```
#!/login/[parametro1]/[parametro2]
```

No seu exemplo, ficaria assim:

```
#!/login/10/20
```